# OSX Very Unstable

Tags: eclipse, macos

I am a new macOS user.

I am a developer who has used Eclipse IDE for a long time without issues. I recently purchased a MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra.

`Eclipse Neon.2` has been unstable in this environment.

My Eclipse was hanging after startup, so I read that I should delete:

```
/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/jbosswildfly/.indexes
```

I started up Eclipse, and it was working. Then I rebooted the machine, and now my project is gone. The project name is still in package explorer, but there is nothing in it (I can't expand it).

[image]

Even after adding back the deleted files, it still has the same problem.

**Question**

What are other developers experience like with `MacOS`? Before I tried it, I heard that it was supposed to be more stable than Windows, but in my experience the opposite is true.

Comment: As it happens Eclipse on macOS is extremely stable for me, but which plugins are installed varies enormously between different Eclipse installs - it only takes one misbehaving plugin to cause problems.

Comment: I am using a RedHat plugin, perhaps it's that. Although that was stable on Windows.

Comment: I removed the RedHat plugin and it seems better...hopefully.

Comment: Having problems with Eclipse on MacOS is mostly due to Eclipse itself not MacOS. I used OSX since the beginning and I certainly would not qualify it as unstable. Each time I use Eclipse on any platform let me think that Eclipse is too often unstable, especially after adding too many various plugins...

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is as stable on macOS as on any other UNIX. I've been using it for a few years on a Mac.

As for your problem, the project is not gone; you have closed your project.
Right click the blue jbosswildfly folder, doing so opens a menu from which you can click "Open Project".

Comment: Thanks for the info, but the project is still on the disk, but Eclipse cannot open it. I found I have needed to create a new workspace and import the project again.  I also find that I have removed the OpenShift plugin, and it seems more stable now. The plugin did work on Windows, pity it doesn't work well on Mac, because it does provide some useful feature to sync with the remote server.

Comment: Eclipse has started freezing again, even after no changed to Eclipse. All I did was reboot the MacBook.  Also my MySQL Workbench freezes when trying to execute a simple SQL statement. I never had any of these problems on Windows.